# "undecompilable" source code in java

Tags: java, java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jar executable that cannot be decompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919690/jar-executable-that-cannot-be-decompiled)

How can I make "undecompilable" source in java? I have a microedition app that has code that I need to hide
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This question has been asked *many* times before in many guises.  The answers are 1) use an obfuscator, and 2) even that won't stop a determined reverse engineer.

Comment: Stephen C is right. Here's an interesting-looking book on the subject that isn't referenced in the cross-referenced question: http://apress.com/book/view/9781590592656

Answer (score 2):

You can't. See this question:
[make your Jar not to be decompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919690/jar-executable-that-cannot-be-decompiled)

Interesting-looking book on the subject:
http://apress.com/book/view/9781590592656

Comment: +1 to counteract the senseless -1.

Comment: @Andrew That's how voting works. Senseless to you, senseful to someone else. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make code undecompilable, you can only obfuscate it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

Answer (score 1):

In short. You can obfuscate your code to make it difficult for someone to read it and reuse it. If that is what you want, it could also make it difficult for someone to see what it does. But not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try obfuscation, but nobody will want to steal your sauce code anyway, so I guess it's more for peace of mind. When it comes down to it, everything is decompilable to a degree, otherwise operating systems wouldn't be able to run any programs!

Comment: Huh? I don't get the part about operating systems...

Comment: If an operating system can convert the data in an executable to processor instructions, then that can be converted into assembly, which can theoretically at least, be converted to any programming language known to man, even LOLCODE.

Comment: @Mchl: Even binary machine code has to mean something, and can therefore be translated into a higher-level representation with some difficulty

Comment: That's seems a bit like circular logic to me, but I guess technically it is true.

Comment: This is irrelevant, but is the "sauce" in "sauce" code intentional :P I initially read the line as "secret sauce"

Comment: Yeah, I replace sauce with source all the time, it's so much more tasty :D

Answer (score -3):

If you want your users to actually, you know, *use* the program, they need to be able to *run* the program. In order to be able to run the program, the CPU must be able to *understand* the program. CPUs are much stupider than humans, so this means that humans can understand the program, too.

If you obfuscate your program in such a way that it cannot be understood by humans, this also means that it cannot be executed.

If you don't want people to get access to your code, there is only one way: don't give it to them. Put it on a server and let your users connect to it via the network.

But all of that is completely unnecessary, since your code is automatically protected by copyright law anyway, which is much more powerful than any obfuscation.

Comment: The code is inside cellphones, I don't hide it

Comment: örg Well, what you write is only true in theory, and even so, only on a very generalized level. Certainly there are ways to "obfuscate your program in such a way that it cannot be understood by humans" but keep it working. Perhaps not in this specific technical context though.