# How to prevent jar decompilation

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I have created a plugin project in Eclipse, distributed as a jar.
The user can take this jar and decompile it using JAD. 
**Is there any way so that i can stop the decompilation of a jar file?**
Or, at least, to hide my source code from the user?

Comment: Please edit your question because it's really hard to understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undecompilable" source code in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797055/undecompilable-source-code-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't insert your source code in the jar, your sourcecode isn't what is decompiled by a decompiler, but something similar.

However, you may use an obfuscator to make code decompilation produce very ugly code like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator,
>   and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields,
>   methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused
>   instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods
>   using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed
>   code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.

Search for other products with the term *obfuscator*.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to stop your jar from being decompiled is to give users no reason to want to. Obfuscation is just a bandaid. In fact, some people will probably reverse it just for the challenge if it's famous enough.

Comment: +1 What a great answer! "You're a lot more likely to beat would-be pirates through frequent, meaningful updates than you are by bothering your customers with increasingly onerous security measures." http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/obfuscating-code.html

Comment: Agree, because if your code transferred and executed into another environment / host - it could be: stopped, debugged, evaluated, transformed etc. You only **could try** to harden this or, as @Antimony said, give no reason to do it: 1) use technologies that require a more higher level of knowledge to decompile (see f.e. http://www.jproductivity.com/); 2) have a low price for your product, 3) use cloud/server logic (don't move code to the client). Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443542/how-to-protect-compiled-java-classes