# Make unDecompilable Exe from jar

Tags: java, jar, exe

how to prevent java code from being decompiled? Suggest any link or suggestions to do so

Comment: Everything can be reverse-engineered.

Comment: Don' use "as soon as possible" in your questions, even if they are "kindest". Besides that, you may want to look for Obfuscation.

Comment: You can Decompile everything in this world...(If not , it applies for jva)

Answer (score 2):

I don' think you can.

Here is another question, which covers this topic:

[make your Jar not to be decompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919690/jar-executable-that-cannot-be-decompiled)

A better bet might be obfuscation. It scrambles all names in the source code, so that it becomes unreadable even if it is still compilable.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are talking about Java [`obfuscation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) which makes your code difficult (but not impossible) to decompile. You can check some open source obfuscation tools from [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators). One of the obfuscation tool that I personally like is `ProGuard`.