# How to add security to Spring boot jar file?

Tags: security, spring-boot

I am able to build standalone spring boot jar file using maven and able to run it using

```
java -jar <jarname>
```

I would like to add security to this jar file such a way that NO one is able to unzip the jar file and see my classes/code.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's useful or not to you, there's no way you can achieve what you want, which is explained in the answers.

Comment: What you are asking is, bank where we can save money but withdrawing the money is never possible. You can not restrict JRE to see what all code you have.. but might be this discussion will help you understand the scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919690/make-your-jar-not-to-be-decompiled